# Track whether user completes call after clicking tel: link

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, tracking, tel

I am working on a page which has a button whose onclick function looks like this

```
handleClick: function () {
    var url = "tel:" + PHONE_NUMBER;
    window.location = url;
},
```

The problem is this. I don't just want to track whether or not the user clicks the button, I also want to track whether or not the user actually places the call. Is there a way to do this? I need methods for both IOS and android.

EDIT: it seems like this isn't possible (and rightly so), but I am still looking for hacky ways to guess at it. For instance, is there a way to check whether or not the browser goes to the background between two page actions in IOS?

Comment: There is no way to do this in JavaScript. That is OS-level functionality.

Comment: darn. Do you know of any hacky way to get a good guess? For instance, when the IOS lightbox pops up, is it possible to determine whether the user went straight back to the page (ie clicked cancel) or launched the phone app (ie clicked call)?

Comment: Hopefully what you are seeking is impossible, for privacy reasons. A Web page has no business, at all, in spying on phone usage.

Comment: What you can do is create a service on the OS level that checks whether the user places the call, and you can have your page talk to that service via Ajax or Websockets.

Comment: @DanielWeiner in theory, how would I get a user to download such a service? This seems out of the realm of a  mobile web application

Comment: You can't force the user to download anything, so yeah, that's a big barrier. 
You can also use a service like [Twilio](http://twilio.com) to make calls; I believe you can do VoIP with Twilio. It's an alternative to making OS-level calls.

Comment: @DanielWeiner Thanks! Unfortunately, I don't think a third party service is an option for me, but that's a great idea in principal